# Order of stacked HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking at a jQuery screencast ([jQuery for Absolute Beginners: Day 8](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-day-8/)).  It has this code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.wrap').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('.front').stop().animate({
      "top": '300px'
    }, 900);
  }, function() {
    $(this).children('.front').stop().animate({
      "top": '0'
    }, 700);
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 850px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.wrap {
  width: 250px;
  height: 140px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <img src="back.jpg" alt="image" />
    <img src="front.jpg" class="front" alt="image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Why is it that front.jpg appears on top of back.jpg?  Is it simply because front.jpg is in a tag that comes after back.jpg's tag?

Comment: This should really be tagged html, css.  I'd also recommend you get a lot more familiar with html/css before delving into jquery, as it is generally used to manipulating the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When z-index is omitted, following siblings are automatically on a higher layer than previous siblings. This is expected behaviour.

To quote from the MDC pages below:

> When no element has a z-index, elements are stacked in this order (from bottom to top):
>
> 1. Background and borders of the root element
> 2. Descendant blocks in the normal flow, in order of appearance (in HTML)
> 3. Descendant positioned elements, in order of appearance (in HTML)

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/understanding_css_z-index and in particular, the first section, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index/Stacking_without_z-index

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943560/html-alignment-issue-in-one-machine-only-both-ie8 ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a bit of a fluke... z-index should really be set on both to make sure.